# How to find the value of exponent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, exponent

Is there a Math API in javascript to find the value of `n` (exponent), eg,

Find the value `n` such that `2**n=64`.

i know there is Math.pow , but it requires base and exponent. In my case i have base and the result, so i dont think it would work.

Comment: Did you take algebra in high school? The inverse of exponent is logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2) .

`Math.log2(x) // x=64`

The `link` will also tell you about other related `Math` functions.
Also remember that for finding `log` of `x` to the base `y`, you can always use the formula `ln(x)/ln(y)` and for `ln` you already have an inbuilt function (Refer link above).

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean to find [log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) of the value

```js
let a = Math.pow(2, 5);
function getBaseLog(x, y) {
  return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
}
console.log(a, getBaseLog(2, a));
```